# Participle and gerund

Tags: gerunds, participles

Barking dogs seldom bite.

Barking is  a gerund or present participle?

His rising early in the morning, helped him score well.

His rising early in the morning   -- is this a participle clause?
Can someone explain how to identify an participle clause in any sentence

Comment: In this case barking is a present participle; it's an adjective modifying **dogs**.

Comment: If it functions as a noun then it's a gerund.  In the second example "rising" is clearly a noun so it's a gerund.

Comment: This question hinges on your simply not looking up what a gerund is. A gerund is a present participle acting as a noun. Try replacing *barking* with another noun. Can you do that? Now try replacing *rising* with another noun. Can you do that?

Comment: @John Clifford Many grammarians regard participial adjectives as true adjectives rather than participles. Certainly with 'bored student' say, the verbal connection is almost entirely bleached out.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Having had 8 months to think about it, I'll go ahead and assume that you have a valid point there. :)

Answer (score 0):

*Barking dogs seldom bite* - "Barking" is a participial adjective modifying "dogs."

*His rising early in the morning* (preferably without a comma) *helped him score well* - "Rising" is a gerund, and the surrounding verbiage is a gerund phrase, acting as the subject of the sentence.

Comment: The correct answer (with your usage of the term 'gerund', which is almost certainly the most common), but it would have been better to do a quick check to see how many times it's been given before on ELU.